# como Retornar al inicio de la aplicacion en Psint

Tags: pseint

estoy haciendo un programa en psint, pero al momento de ingresar un dato no deseado se manda una alerta mas no se reinicia la opción para que el usuario vuelva a ingresar el dato solo finaliza el programa.

[image: imagen donde a momento de ingresar un dato incorrecto manda mensaje mas no se reinicia el programa solo finaliza]

anexo una parte  del codigo:

```
Algoritmo rentaDeVehiculos
Escribir 'Autos UP Bienbenido'
Escribir 'Seleccione_Un_vehiculo 1=ferrari 2=bochito 3=moto'
Leer lista_de_variables
Segun lista_de_variables  Hacer
    1:
        Escribir 'ferrari_1500'
        Escribir 'CantidadDeDias'
        Leer diasFe
        Mientras diasFe<1 Hacer
            Escribir 'Datos incorrectos intentelo de nuevo'
            Leer diasFe
        FinMientras
        ferrari <- 1500
        total <- diasFe*ferrari
        Escribir total
    2:
        Escribir 'bochito_1000'
        Escribir 'CantidadDeDias'
        Leer diasBo
        Mientras diasBo<1 Hacer
            Escribir 'Datos incorrectos intentelo de nuevo'
            Leer diasBo
        FinMientras
        bocho <- 1000
        total <- diasBo*bocho
        Escribir total
    
    De Otro Modo:
        Escribir 'Dato, NO reconocido'
FinSegun
```

FinAlgoritmo

Comment: Deberias envolver todo en alguna clase de ciclo mientras... con una bandera que indique cuando termino...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como te decia el compañero @gbianchi deberia de colocar tu script dentro de un bucle y utilizar una estructura de control para detener dicho bucle.

en este escenario implemento: `Repetir`, `Hasta Que`

```
Algoritmo rentaDeVehiculos
    OP <- 0
    Repetir
    Escribir 'Autos UP Bienbenido'
    Escribir 'Seleccione_Un_vehiculo 1=ferrari 2=bochito 3=moto'
    Leer lista_de_variables
    Segun lista_de_variables  Hacer
        1:
            Escribir 'ferrari_1500'
            Escribir 'CantidadDeDias'
            Leer diasFe
            Mientras diasFe<1 Hacer
                Escribir 'Datos incorrectos intentelo de nuevo'
                Leer diasFe
            FinMientras
            ferrari <- 1500
            total <- diasFe*ferrari
            Escribir total
            OP <- 1
        2:
            Escribir 'bochito_1000'
            Escribir 'CantidadDeDias'
            Leer diasBo
            Mientras diasBo<1 Hacer
                Escribir 'Datos incorrectos intentelo de nuevo'
                Leer diasBo
            FinMientras
            bocho <- 1000
            total <- diasBo*bocho
            Escribir total
            OP <- 1
            
        De Otro Modo:
            Escribir 'Dato, NO reconocido'
    FinSegun
Hasta Que OP=1
FinAlgoritmo
```

Algoritmo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

un poco mas avanzado con funciones seria este ejemplo:

```
Funcion leerTipo( tipo por referencia)
    Repetir
        Escribir 'Autos UP Bienbenido'
        Escribir 'Seleccione Un vehiculo: 1=ferrari 2=bochito 3=moto'
        Leer tipo
    Hasta Que tipo <> 0 y tipo < 4
FinFuncion

Funcion leerDias( dias por referencia)
    Repetir
        Escribir 'Seleccione la cantidad de dias de Alquiler:'
        Leer dias
    Hasta Que dias > 0
FinFuncion

Funcion calcularAlquiler( tipo, dias)
    total = 0
    Segun tipo  Hacer
        1:
            // Ferrari
            total <- 1500*dias
        2:
            // Bocho
            total <- 1000*dias
        3:
            // Moto
            total <- 500*dias
    FinSegun
    
    Escribir 'Total ',total
    
FinFuncion

Funcion deseaSalir( out por referencia)
    Escribir 'Desea salir; 1 para salir, 0 para continuar:'
    Leer out
FinFuncion

Algoritmo rentaDeVehiculos
    Repetir
        Limpiar Pantalla
        out <- 0
        tipo <- 0
        dias <- 0
        leerTipo(tipo)
        leerdias(dias)
        calcularAlquiler(tipo,dias)
        deseaSalir(out)
    Hasta Que out = 1
FinAlgoritmo
```

Ahora el algoritmo no muestra las relacion entre las funciones, tube que hacer un apaño en power point para demostrarlas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]